# Issues with partially formatting text in Visio using Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, text, formatting, visio

I've seen in VBA examples, that partially formatting a Visio shape-text makes use of the characters.begin and characters.end properties to select the part of the text to format.

Now I'm having issues in adapting this to my Powershell script - the begin property seems to be read only:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).getType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name         BaseType
-------- -------- ----         --------                  
True     False    ShapeClass                               System.__ComObject
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).Text
Hello World
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).Characters.Begin
0
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).Characters.End
11
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).Characters.CharCount
11
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).Characters.End = 5
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $visioObjects.($_.key).Characters.End 
11
```

Here is the code in short for reproduction:

```
$appVisio = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$docsObj = $appVisio.Documents
$docObj = $docsObj.Add("")

# Set the active page of the document to page 1
$pagsObj = $appVisio.ActiveDocument.Pages
$pagObj = $pagsObj.Item(1)
$shpObj = $pagObj.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
$shpObj.text = 'Hello World'
$shpObj.Characters.Begin = 5 # <======================== Won't accept
$shpObj.Characters.Begin # <======================== Returns 0, makes me cry
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Comment: Here's [the property in question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767252.aspx) for anyone that wants to take a shake at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually one level up the chain from where you're working. `Begin` is a read-write property, but `Shape.Characters` is read-only (**[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768585.aspx)**).

While you can't modify `$shpObj.Characters.Begin` directly, you *can* do something like this:

```
$chars = $shpObj.Characters
$chars.Begin = 5
```

And then proceed to use `$chars` the way you were going to use `$shpObj.Characters`.